# Outlook for MacOS: starting my reply after the previous email

Tags: email, ms-office

in Mail.app I can set that my reply to an email starts under the text of said email -- I do not seem to have this setting in Outlook (also, I'd like to make sure I send plain text emails not HTML, and I cannot find that setting either). I am using Outlook from the Apple Store.

Comment: Most people find that annoying, that they have to scroll past the quoted section before they can find the new information. This is a very 90's approach to email, more akin to usenet usage & has fallen very much out of favour in the past 20 years. Etiquette dictates the new post goes at the top these days.

Comment: @Tetsujin my email, my choice? especially because I work with people who insist in proper quoting (to the point I need to reply to each question Immediately under it), and as thing stands my own signature ends up at the top of the email, as if I were a total idiot. Proper quoting, BTW, is 90's quoting. *That* is the way.